# BDD How would you improve this Gherkin spec?

Tags: tdd, bdd

I'm working in a [GTD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getting_Things_Done) implementation, and I'm a bit messy about how to specificate system's behavior in order to follow the [GTD's workflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getting_Things_Done#Workflow).

I'm also working through BDD, that's why i need to specificate the best I can how the sistem should behave with user interactions and other external events.

This is my current feature file:

```
# language: en
Feature: Clarifier
  This feature should allow the user to convert already extracted inputs into organizeable ones.

  Scenario: User clarifies an input giving it subjective meaning
    Since I have inputs to clarify
    When the system shows me one input at a time ordered by priority
    And tell me to enter into the system what that input means to me
    So I should record my response related to that input.

  @clarify_actionability
  Scenario: User clarifies the actionability of an input as actionable
    Since I have inputs to clarify
    When I indicate to the system that I want to clarify an input that already makes subjective sense
    So the system should ask me for each input if it is actionable or not
    And I should record my response related to that input

  @clarify_actionability
  Scenario: User tries to clarify the actionability of an input that does not make subjective sense
    Since I have inputs to clarify
    When I try to clarify one that doesn't make subjective sense
    So the system should not allow me to clarify it
    And you should inform me that I cannot clarify the actionability of an input that does not make subjective sense.
    
  @clarify_how many_steps
  Scenario: User clarifies an indicated input actionable as a single step
    Since one or more inputs are indicated as actionable
    When I indicate to the system that I want to indicate one or more as actionable in a single step
    Then the system should record my response related to that/those input/s

  @clarify_how many_steps
  Scenario: User tries to clarify an input as a single step without indicating it as actionable
    Since one or more inputs were not indicated as actionable
    When I try to indicate to the system that I want to indicate one or more as one-step actionable
    So the system should not record my response related to that/those input/s
    And you should inform me that I cannot clarify the number of actions of an input that is not actionable.

  @plan_project
  Scenario: User wants to plan a project for an actionable
    Since I have inputs with subjective meaning
    When indicating that one is actionable
    And indicate that it is not one-step
    So the system should allow me to plan a project
    And register it in the system
```

How can I to define "sequential work" in my feature files?
How can I to specificate how i want the presentation layer (UI) to work in order to follow business logics (I'm in troubles here, because I don't know how to keep cohesion with business logic without coupling in UI)